# error System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in AttLogs.exe

Tags: c#, exception, dll, windows

I am developing a C#.net windows application .I use zkemkeeper DLL in my project.
So I want to connect to Device .When I run the project .I get below exception.

Additional information: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00853A19-BD51-419B-9269-2DABE57EB61F} failed due to the following error: 80040154.
Please Help me to solve this problem

Code :

```
/**********************************************************
 * Demo for Standalone SDK.Created by Darcy on Oct.15 2009*
***********************************************************/
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AttLogs
{
    public partial class AttLogsMain : Form
    {
        public AttLogsMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        //Create Standalone SDK class dynamicly.
        public zkemkeeper.CZKEMClass axCZKEM1 = new zkemkeeper.CZKEMClass();

        /********************************************************************************************************************************************
        * Before you refer to this demo,we strongly suggest you read the development manual deeply first.                                           *
        * This part is for demonstrating the communication with your device.There are 3 communication ways: "TCP/IP","Serial Port" and "USB Client".*
        * The communication way which you can use duing to the model of the device.                                                                 *
        * *******************************************************************************************************************************************/
        #region Communication
        private bool bIsConnected = false;//the boolean value identifies whether the device is connected
        private int iMachineNumber = 1;//the serial number of the device.After connecting the device ,this value will be changed.

        //If your device supports the TCP/IP communications, you can refer to this.
        //when you are using the tcp/ip communication,you can distinguish different devices by their IP address.
        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtIP.Text.Trim() == "" || txtPort.Text.Trim() == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("IP and Port cannot be null", "Error");
                return;
            }
            int idwErrorCode = 0;

            Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            if (btnConnect.Text == "DisConnect")
            {
                axCZKEM1.Disconnect();
                bIsConnected = false;
                btnConnect.Text = "Connect";
                lblState.Text = "Current State:DisConnected";
                Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                return;
            }

            bIsConnected = axCZKEM1.Connect_Net(txtIP.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtPort.Text));
            if (bIsConnected == true)
            {
                btnConnect.Text = "DisConnect";
                btnConnect.Refresh();
                lblState.Text = "Current State:Connected";
                iMachineNumber = 1;//In fact,when you are using the tcp/ip communication,this parameter will be ignored,that is any integer will all right.Here we use 1.
                axCZKEM1.RegEvent(iMachineNumber, 65535);//Here you can register the realtime events that you want to be triggered(the parameters 65535 means registering all)
            }
            else
            {
                axCZKEM1.GetLastError(ref idwErrorCode);
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect the device,ErrorCode=" + idwErrorCode.ToString(), "Error");
            }
            Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }

        //If your device supports the SerialPort communications, you can refer to this.
        private void btnRsConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cbPort.Text.Trim() == "" || cbBaudRate.Text.Trim() == "" || txtMachineSN.Text.Trim() == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Port,BaudRate and MachineSN cannot be null", "Error");
                return;
            }
            int idwErrorCode = 0;
            //accept serialport number from string like "COMi"
            int iPort;
            string sPort = cbPort.Text.Trim();
            for (iPort = 1; iPort < 10; iPort++)
            {
                if (sPort.IndexOf(iPort.ToString()) > -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            if (btnRsConnect.Text == "Disconnect")
            {
                axCZKEM1.Disconnect();
                bIsConnected = false;
                btnRsConnect.Text = "Connect";
                btnRsConnect.Refresh();
                lblState.Text = "Current State:Disconnected";
                Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                return;
            }

            iMachineNumber = Convert.ToInt32(txtMachineSN.Text.Trim());//when you are using the serial port communication,you can distinguish different devices by their serial port number.
            bIsConnected = axCZKEM1.Connect_Com(iPort, iMachineNumber, Convert.ToInt32(cbBaudRate.Text.Trim()));

            if (bIsConnected == true)
            {
                btnRsConnect.Text = "Disconnect";
                btnRsConnect.Refresh();
                lblState.Text = "Current State:Connected";

                axCZKEM1.RegEvent(iMachineNumber, 65535);//Here you can register the realtime events that you want to be triggered(the parameters 65535 means registering all)
            }
            else
            {
                axCZKEM1.GetLastError(ref idwErrorCode);
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect the device,ErrorCode=" + idwErrorCode.ToString(), "Error");
            }

            Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }

        //If your device supports the USBCLient, you can refer to this.
        //Not all series devices can support this kind of connection.Please make sure your device supports USBClient.
        private void btnUSBConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int idwErrorCode = 0;

            Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

            if (btnUSBConnect.Text == "Disconnect")
            {
                axCZKEM1.Disconnect();
                bIsConnected = false;
                btnUSBConnect.Text = "Connect";
                btnUSBConnect.Refresh();
                lblState.Text = "Current State:Disconnected";
                Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                return;
            }

            if (rbUSB.Checked == true)//the common USBClient
            {
                iMachineNumber = 1;//In fact,when you are using common USBClient communication,parameter Machinenumber will be ignored,that is any integer will all right.Here we use 1.
                bIsConnected = axCZKEM1.Connect_USB(iMachineNumber);
            }
            else
                if (rbVUSB.Checked == true)//connect the device via the virtual serial port created by USB
                {
                    SearchforUSBCom usbcom = new SearchforUSBCom();
                    string sCom = "";
                    bool bSearch = usbcom.SearchforCom(ref sCom);//modify by Darcy on Nov.26 2009
                    if (bSearch == false)//modify by Darcy on Nov.26 2009
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Can not find the virtual serial port that can be used", "Error");
                        Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                        return;
                    }

                    int iPort;
                    for (iPort = 1; iPort < 10; iPort++)
                    {
                        if (sCom.IndexOf(iPort.ToString()) > -1)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    iMachineNumber = Convert.ToInt32(txtMachineSN2.Text.Trim());
                    if (iMachineNumber == 0 || iMachineNumber > 255)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("The Machine Number is invalid!", "Error");
                        Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                        return;
                    }

                    int iBaudRate = 115200;//115200 is one possible baudrate value(its value cannot be 0)
                    bIsConnected = axCZKEM1.Connect_Com(iPort, iMachineNumber, iBaudRate);
                }

            if (bIsConnected == true)
            {
                btnUSBConnect.Text = "Disconnect";
                btnUSBConnect.Refresh();
                lblState.Text = "Current State:Connected";
                axCZKEM1.RegEvent(iMachineNumber, 65535);//Here you can register the realtime events that you want to be triggered(the parameters 65535 means registering all)
            }
            else
            {
                axCZKEM1.GetLastError(ref idwErrorCode);
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect the device,ErrorCode=" + idwErrorCode.ToString(), "Error");
            }

            Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }

        private void rbVUSB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (rbVUSB.Checked == true)
            {
                if (bIsConnected == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Operation!", "Error");
                    rbVUSB.Checked = false;
                    return;
                }
                rbUSB.Checked = false;
                txtMachineSN2.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void rbUSB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (rbUSB.Checked == true)
            {
                if (bIsConnected == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Operation!", "Error");
                    rbUSB.Checked = false;
                    return;
                }
                rbVUSB.Checked = false;
                txtMachineSN2.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        /*************************************************************************************************
        * Before you refer to this demo,we strongly suggest you read the development manual deeply first.*
        * This part is for demonstrating operations with(read/get/clear) the attendance records.         *
        * ************************************************************************************************/
        #region AttLogs

        //Download the attendance records from the device.
        private void btnGetGeneralLogData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (bIsConnected == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please connect the device first", "Error");
                return;
            }

            int idwTMachineNumber=0;
            int idwEnrollNumber = 0;
            int idwEMachineNumber=0;
            int idwVerifyMode=0;
            int idwInOutMode=0;
            int idwYear=0;
            int idwMonth=0;
            int idwDay=0;
            int idwHour=0;
            int idwMinute=0;

            int idwErrorCode=0;
            int iGLCount = 0;
            int iIndex = 0;

            Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            lvLogs.Items.Clear();
            axCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, false);//disable the device
            if (axCZKEM1.ReadGeneralLogData(iMachineNumber))//read all the attendance records to the memory
            {
                while (axCZKEM1.GetGeneralLogData(iMachineNumber, ref idwTMachineNumber, ref idwEnrollNumber,
                        ref idwEMachineNumber, ref idwVerifyMode, ref idwInOutMode, ref idwYear, ref idwMonth, ref idwDay, ref idwHour, ref idwMinute))//get records from the memory
                {
                    iGLCount++;
                    lvLogs.Items.Add(iGLCount.ToString());
                    lvLogs.Items[iIndex].SubItems.Add(idwEnrollNumber.ToString());
                    lvLogs.Items[iIndex].SubItems.Add(idwVerifyMode.ToString());
                    lvLogs.Items[iIndex].SubItems.Add(idwInOutMode.ToString());
                    lvLogs.Items[iIndex].SubItems.Add(idwYear.ToString() + "-" + idwMonth.ToString() + "-" + idwDay.ToString() + " " + idwHour.ToString() + ":" + idwMinute.ToString());
                    iIndex++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                axCZKEM1.GetLastError(ref idwErrorCode);

                if (idwErrorCode != 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Reading data from terminal failed,ErrorCode: " + idwErrorCode.ToString(),"Error");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No data from terminal returns!","Error");
                }
            }
            axCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, true);//enable the device
            Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }

        //Download the attendance records from the device.
        //The returned time is in strings(different from function GetGeneralLogData)
        private void btnGetGeneralLogDataStr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (bIsConnected == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please connect the device first", "Error");
                return;
            }          
            int idwErrorCode = 0;

            int idwEnrollNumber = 0;
            int idwVerifyMode = 0;
            int idwInOutMode = 0;
            string sTime = "";

            int iGLCount = 0;
            int iIndex = 0;

            Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            lvLogs.Items.Clear();
            axCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, false);//disable the device
            if (axCZKEM1.ReadGeneralLogData(iMachineNumber))//read the records to the memory
            {
                while (axCZKEM1.GetGeneralLogDataStr(iMachineNumber, ref idwEnrollNumber, ref idwVerifyMode, ref idwInOutMode, ref sTime))//get the records from memory
                {
                    iGLCount++;
                    lvLogs.Items.Add(iGLCount.ToString());
                    lvLogs.Items[iIndex].SubItems.Add(idwEnrollNumber.ToString());
                    lvLogs.Items[iIndex].SubItems.Add(idwVerifyMode.ToString());
                    lvLogs.Items[iIndex].SubItems.Add(idwInOutMode.ToString());
                    lvLogs.Items[iIndex].SubItems.Add(sTime);
                    iIndex++;
                }
　　        }
            else
            {
                Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                axCZKEM1.GetLastError(ref idwErrorCode);

                if (idwErrorCode != 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Reading data from terminal failed,ErrorCode: " + idwErrorCode.ToString(), "Error");
                }
                else
                {
                    axCZKEM1.GetLastError(ref idwErrorCode);
                    MessageBox.Show("Operation failed,ErrorCode=" + idwErrorCode.ToString(), "Error");
                }
            }
            axCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, true);//enable the device
            Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }

        //Download the attendance records from the device.
        //"GetGeneralExtLogData" is an enhanced function of the function GetGeneralLogData, but it is compatible with GetGeneralLogData. 
        //Some machines have the WorkCode function; this function can gain the WorkCode when user passes the virification.
        private void btnGetGeneralExtLogData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (bIsConnected == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please connect the device first", "Error");
                return;
            }

            int idwErrorCode = 0;

            int idwEnrollNumber = 0;
            int idwVerifyMode = 0;
            int idwInOutMode = 0;

            int idwYear = 0;
            int idwMonth = 0;
            int idwDay = 0;
            int idwHour = 0;
            int idwMinute = 0;
            int idwSecond = 0;
            int idwWorkCode = 0;
            int idwReserved = 0;

            int iGLCount = 0;
            int iIndex = 0;

            Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            lvLogs.Items.Clear();
            axCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, false);//disable the device
            if (axCZKEM1.ReadGeneralLogData(iMachineNumber))//read all the attendance records to the memory
            {
                while (axCZKEM1.GetGeneralExtLogData(iMachineNumber, ref idwEnrollNumber, ref idwVerifyMode, ref idwInOutMode,
                         ref idwYear, ref idwMonth, ref idwDay, ref idwHour, ref idwMinute, ref idwSecond, ref idwWorkCode, ref idwReserved))//get records from the memory
                {
                    iGLCount++;
                    lvLogs.Items.Add(iGLCount.ToString());
                    lvLogs.Items[iIndex].SubItems.Add(idwEnrollNumber.ToString());
                    lvLogs.Items[iIndex].SubItems.Add(idwVerifyMode.ToString());
                    lvLogs.Items[iIndex].SubItems.Add(idwInOutMode.ToString());
                    lvLogs.Items[iIndex].SubItems.Add(idwYear.ToString() + "-" + idwMonth.ToString() + "-" + idwDay.ToString() + " " + idwHour.ToString() + ":" + idwMinute.ToString() + ":" + idwSecond.ToString());
                    lvLogs.Items[iIndex].SubItems.Add(idwWorkCode.ToString());
                    lvLogs.Items[iIndex].SubItems.Add(idwReserved.ToString());
                    iIndex++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                axCZKEM1.GetLastError(ref idwErrorCode);

                if (idwErrorCode != 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Reading data from terminal failed,ErrorCode: " + idwErrorCode.ToString(), "Error");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No data from terminal returns!", "Error");
                }
            }
            axCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, true);//enable the device
            Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }

        //Clear all attendance records from terminal.
        private void btnClearGLog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (bIsConnected == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please connect the device first", "Error");
                return;
            }
            int idwErrorCode = 0;

            lvLogs.Items.Clear();
            axCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, false);//disable the device
            if (axCZKEM1.ClearGLog(iMachineNumber))
            {
                axCZKEM1.RefreshData(iMachineNumber);//the data in the device should be refreshed
                MessageBox.Show("All att Logs have been cleared from teiminal!", "Success");
            }
            else
            {
                axCZKEM1.GetLastError(ref idwErrorCode);
                MessageBox.Show("Operation failed,ErrorCode=" + idwErrorCode.ToString(), "Error");
            }
            axCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, true);//enable the device
        }

        //Get the count of attendance records in from ternimal.
        private void btnGetDeviceStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (bIsConnected == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please connect the device first", "Error");
                return;
            }
            int idwErrorCode = 0;
            int iValue = 0;

            axCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, false);//disable the device
            if (axCZKEM1.GetDeviceStatus(iMachineNumber, 6, ref iValue)) //Here we use the function "GetDeviceStatus" to get the record's count.The parameter "Status" is 6.
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The count of the AttLogs in the device is " + iValue.ToString(), "Success");
            }
            else
            {
                axCZKEM1.GetLastError(ref idwErrorCode);
                MessageBox.Show("Operation failed,ErrorCode=" + idwErrorCode.ToString(), "Error");
            }
            axCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, true);//enable the device
        }
        #endregion

        private void AttLogsMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you failing?  Are you trying to connect using serial port, usb, or TCP.  Be more specific.

Comment: When I run the project .before running this Exception raised.

Comment: You have not provided any useful information for me to be able to help.  InteopService errors usually refer to errors interface with Microsoft Office.  There is no office interface in the posted code so I suspect the dll requires a version of Office that you do not have installed on the PC.  This is only a guess.

Comment: 80040154 is `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREGISTERED`, "Class not registered". One obvious way this can happen is if your COM component only has a 32-bit DLL and your application runs as 64-bit, or vice versa. Another common error is failing to register the class at all (not installing the COM component in question).